# How to write a reusable component for axios.get and axios.post?

Tags: reactjs

I am a student focusing on front-end development, mostly React and JavaScript. I got into problem now, I am using axios but in future there will be other library like axios that is more flexible. I am fed up writing an axios call every time in action creators. I want to write a reusable component for my API methods, like I can drag them into my reducer file to use it. when I want to change it I don't have go through all my components to change `axios.get`.

```
import Axios from 'axios'


 export function GetApiData() {
        return function () {
            Axios.get('/api').then(response=>{
               console.log(response.data);
            });
        }
    }
```

I have heard that in a production environment companies use a reusable component to work this kind of scenario. I am looking for a reusable component, something like this:

```
import {get, post} from 'some file'

// code using get or post to make an axios call
```

and use those get instead for Axios.get. I am bad at creating reusable components.

Comment: You  can have a 'helpers' folder.Where you can do all api calls and then export it like you do other exports

Comment: i am not able to write it in a professional way. i am writing in a simple javascript function but they  are not good as others.

Comment: though i have tried like export function GET(){ writing a code here but it is not not working}

Comment: okay.I am writing

Comment: thank you@Debabrata

Answer (score 0):

in your src folder you can create a folder whatever name you like and inside  it create another js file  whatever name you like.After that do something like this.check if this is what you want

***Note:the snippet will not  run.this is only for demo***

```js
const Client={
    login:(phone,key)=>{
         //here change it  to  your desired function like axios.get or  anything
       return fetch(
            `https://example.com/api/account/login`,
            {
                method:'POST',
                accept:'application/json',
            }
        ).then((response)=>response.json());
    },
    //write bunch of methods like the above

}



export default Client;
```

After that import it to wherever you want to use it.Use it  and tell me if any problem occured

say you want to use it in a file
you can do

```
import Client from "yourfoldername/filename";


//call to client
 // i believe your api call returns a promise
Client.login(parameters).then((res)=>{
      //do something here
  }
).catch(err=>{
    //do something here
})
```